# Is there any way to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have seen an answer (in terms of BesselY and StruveH functions) to this integral:

```
Integrate[E^(-R1/Rd)R1/Sqrt[R1^2+z^2],{R1,0,Infinity},{f,0,2Pi}]
```

However, it seems that the `Mathematica` cannot do this integration. Have you any idea?

Comment: Did you mean to integrate over $z$ instead of $f$?

Comment: @Roman No, it is just a `2Pi`. I have written the original form :)

Comment: Should z be a function of f?

Comment: @mikado No, the $f$ is actually $\phi$ in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: So why are you integrating over $f$ then, instead of just multiplying by $2\pi$? Please condense your problem to minimal form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral in minimal form would be

```
Integrate[(E^-x x)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> y > 0]
(*    -(1/2) π y (BesselY[1, y] + StruveH[-1, y])    *)
```

More specifically for your case,

```
Integrate[(E^(-(R1/Rd)) R1)/Sqrt[R1^2 + z^2], {R1, 0, ∞},
  Assumptions -> Rd > 0 && z > 0]
(*    -(1/2) π z (BesselY[1, z/Rd] + StruveH[-1, z/Rd])    *)
```

For $z<0$ we should get the same answer if we replace $z$ with $\lvert z \rvert$ in the answer:

```
(*    -(1/2) π Abs[z] (BesselY[1, Abs[z]/Rd] + StruveH[-1, Abs[z]/Rd])    *)
```

Comment: The general answer is true, but $z$ is a coordinate and maybe negative too.

Comment: The integrand only depends on $z^2$ so the result can only depend on $\lvert z\rvert$. I'll update the answer.

Comment: indeed, but it's weird that MMA cannot evaluate the integral if you assume that $z$ is negative, i.e., `Assumptions -> z < 0`.

Comment: Yes @AccidentalFourierTransform and `Assumptions -> Element[z, Reals]` doesn't work either.